# Mostrar imágenes o documentos dependiendo del tipo

Tags: php, html

Tengo un botón que es *tipo file* en el cual puedo subir imágenes y archivos,mi problema se da a la hora de mostrarlos.

```
static function mostrarTodo($amigos)
    {
        $con = conexion("root", "");
        $consulta = $con->prepare("select U.CodUsua, U.nombre, U.foto_perfil, P.CodPost, P.contenido, P.img , p.categoria from usuario U inner join post P on U.CodUsua = P.CodUsua   ORDER BY P.CodPost DESC");
        $consulta->execute();
        $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
        return $resultado;
    }

$post = post::mostrarTodo($amigos[0]['amigos']);

if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $contenido, $url)){


  $contenido= preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $contenido);

}

if(($_FILES['archivo']['type'] == "image/jpeg") ||
      ($_FILES['archivo']['type'] == "image/jpg") ||
       ($_FILES['archivo']['type'] == "image/gif") ||
      ($_FILES['archivo']['type'] == "image/png")
      ){
    $img = empty($_FILES['archivo']['name'])?"vacio":$destino . $_SESSION["CodUsua"] . $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

    $tmp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];

    post::agregar($_SESSION['CodUsua'], $contenido, $img, $categoria);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp, $img);
    }elseif(($_FILES['archivo']['type'] == "application/msword") or
           ($_FILES['archivo']['type'] == "application/msexcel") or 
           ($_FILES['archivo']['type'] == "application/pdf") or
        ($_FILES['archivo']['type'] == "application/x-zip-compressed") ){

        $tmp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
        $img = empty($_FILES['archivo']['name'])?"vacio":$destino. $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, $img);
 $img='<a class="icon-download3" href="../subidos/'.$nombre.'"download>Descargar</a>';



        post::agregar($_SESSION['CodUsua'], $contenido, $img, $categoria);
      }elseif($img="vacio"){

         post::agregar($_SESSION['CodUsua'], $contenido, $img, $categoria);

     } else   {
            echo'<script>
    alert("Formato de archivo invalido");
window.history.go(-1);


   </script>';                   
 }
```

Mi problema se da en esta parte, el primer `div` sirve para mostrar la imagen si es que sube una y el segundo `div` sirve para mostrar un `link` para que pueda descargar el documento... el problema es que no se como hacer para que me identifique si es una foto o es una imagen y pueda tomar el `div` correcto

```
<?php if(!empty($post)): ?>
        <?php foreach($post as $posts): ?>
        <article class="publicacion">
            <div class="publi-info-perfil">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="perfil.php?CodUsua=<?php echo $posts['CodUsua']; ?>"><img src="../subidos/<?php echo $posts['foto_perfil']; ?>" alt="" class="publi-img-perfil"></a></td>
                        <td><a href="perfil.php?CodUsua=<?php echo $posts['CodUsua']; ?>" class="nombre-usuario"><?php echo $posts['nombre']; ?></a></td>
                        <div class="categori"><p><?php echo $posts['categoria']; ?></p>                                 
                        </div>
                    </tr>                   
                </table>
            </div>
        <hr>

    <div class="publi-thumb"><?php if($posts['img']!="vacio"){?>
            <img src="<?php echo $posts['img']; ?>" alt=""></div><?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="publi-thumb"><?php if($posts['img']!="vacio"){?>
         <?php echo $posts['img']; ?></div><?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿De donde sale la variable `$posts`? Además de `$posts['img']`, ¿que otros datos tiene? ¿Podrías agregar en tu respuesta el resultado de hacer `var_dump($posts)` y/o citar algunos ejemplos?

Comment: `static function mostrarTodo($amigos)
 {
  $con = conexion("root", "");
  $consulta = $con->prepare("select U.CodUsua, U.nombre, U.foto_perfil, P.CodPost, P.contenido, P.img , p.categoria from usuario U inner join post P on U.CodUsua = P.CodUsua   ORDER BY P.CodPost DESC");
  $consulta->execute();
  $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
  return $resultado;
 }`

Comment: `$post = post::mostrarTodo($amigos[0]['amigos']);`

Comment: <?php foreach($post as $posts): ?>

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para añadir esa información en la pregunta en sí. En los comentarios el código es difícil de leer

Comment: ya edite la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenemos que `$posts['img']`, si es:

- una image `.jpeg, .jpg, .png o .gif`, es igual al `path` a la misma.
- un archivo `.xls, .xlxs, .doc, .pdf o .zip`, es una cadena que empieza con `<a class....`
- Sino, es igual a `vacio`.

Entonces, lo que podrías hacer seria esto:

```
<?php
  foreach ($post as $posts) { ?>
  ....
<?php
    if ($posts['img'] != "vacio") { ?>
  <div class="publi-thumb">
<?php
      // ACA Si es una imagen
      if (substr($posts['img'], 0, 2) != '<a') { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $posts['img']; ?>" alt="">
<?php
      } else {
        echo $posts['img'];
      } ?>
</div>
<?php
    }// end if ?>
  ...
<?php
  }//end foreach ?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió!!!